# If cell A1 in sheet 1 matches cell B1 in sheet 2, then return cell A1 from sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of suppliers on sheet 1 in column A

I also have a list of suppliers on sheet 2 in column B, with the matching account numbers in column A.

I need a formula that looks at the suppliers in column A of sheet 1 and if that supplier name exists in column B of sheet 2, then it populates sheet 1 with the data found in column A of sheet 2 (the account numbers).

What formula would work best for this?

Comment: Probably VLOOKUP. but hard to say without seeing an example.

Answer (score 0):

XLOOKUP should do the trick.

```
=XLOOKUP(A4;Sheet2!B:B;Sheet2!A:A;"NO_MATCH")
```

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet1

[image: Sheet2]

Sheet2